# Coverage map with Drupal, GMap and Location

Tags: drupal-gmap

I'm using the GMaps, Location and User locations module on my Drupal site. I would like to have a map which can display the "coverage" of my users. The coverage radius is stored in a custom content type with reference to the user.

How is it possible to display users with only their coverage circle on a map? I saw a display type like this when playing with the GMap macros, so I think it would be possible to use GMaps that way.

I suppose most likely this isn't supported out-of-the-box with the GMap module. Anyway, I would be really glad if anybody could point me into the right direction...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to do this after all with the help of the Hungarian community. *(I would be happy to link the original thread, but it seems it got deleted.)*

Basically the "trick" was to make a little custom module with a hook:

```
function MODULENAME_preprocess_gmap_view_gmap(&$vars) {
  if ( $vars['view']->name == "my_gmap_view" ) {
    $map_object = $vars['map_object'];
    $map_object['id'] = 'my_view_id';
    foreach ($vars['view']->result as $key => $row) {
      $shapes[$key]['type'] = 'circle';

      // we have a profile field for the radius, but it could be anything...
      $shapes[$key]['radius'] = $row->profile_values_profile_radius_value;

      // center the circles on the coord
      $shapes[$key]['center'][0] = $row->location_latitude;
      $shapes[$key]['center'][1]= $row->location_longitude;
    }

    // we don't need any markers, just the circles
    $map_object['markers'] = NULL;
    $map_object['shapes'] = $shapes;
    $vars['map'] = theme('gmap', array('#settings' => $map_object));
  }
}
```